# VBA code to bold all numbers within a selection in a textbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to change selected text's font to Arial and size 10, it's quite simple:

```
Sub Arial10()
    With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
    End With
End Sub
```

How can I add to this macro to bold any numbers and dashes ("-") within this selection?

Answer (score 2):

Here it goes....

```
Sub Arial10()
With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 10


End With

'-----BOLD all numbers and dashes-----
With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(.Text)
        If Mid(.Text, i, 1) Like "#" Or _
            Mid(.Text, i, 1) = "-" Then
                .Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Another take:

```
Sub Arial10andBoldStuff()
Dim shp As ShapeRange
Dim i As Long
Dim Char As Object

Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange
With shp.TextFrame2.TextRange
    With .Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
    End With
    For i = 1 To .Characters.Count
        Set Char = .Characters(i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(Char) Or Char = "-" Then
            Char.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Setting the shape to a variable is helpful for getting the Intellisense.